# return rows in laravel that are not empty

Tags: php, json, laravel, select

I have the following output that I am getting from the laravel and I am inserting them in to selectbox as an option. But for the `lunch option` my last options are empty. How can I return rows in laravel that are not empty?

> {"id":18,"guest_origin":"Bulgaria","heard_where":"","staying_at":"","lunch_option":"Cheese"},{"id":19,"guest_origin":"Chech
>   Republic","heard_where":"","staying_at":"","lunch_option":"Chicken"},{"id":20,"guest_origin":"China","heard_where":"","staying_at":"","lunch_option":"Ham"},{"id":21,"guest_origin":"Denmark","heard_where":"","staying_at":"","lunch_option":""},{"id":22,"guest_origin":"Finland","heard_where":"","staying_at":"","lunch_option":""},{"id":23,"guest_origin":"Israel","heard_where":"","staying_at":"","lunch_option":""},{"id":24,"guest_origin":"Malaysia","heard_where":"","staying_at":"","lunch_option":""},{"id":25,"guest_origin":"Norway","heard_where":"","staying_at":"","lunch_option":""},

[image]

controller.php

```
function getComboselect( Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax() == true && \Auth::check() == true)
    {
        $param = explode(':',$request->input('filter'));
        $parent = (!is_null($request->input('parent')) ? $request->input('parent') : null);
        $limit = (!is_null($request->input('limit')) ? $request->input('limit') : null);
        $rows = $this->model->getComboselect($param,$limit,$parent);
        $items = array();
        $fields = explode("|",$param[2]);
        foreach($rows as $row) 
        {
            $value = "";
            foreach($fields as $item=>$val)
            {
                if($val != "") $value .= $row->{$val}." ";
            }
            $items[] = array($row->{$param['1']} , $value);     
        }
    return json_encode($items);     
    }
```

Model.php

```
static function getComboselect( $params , $limit =null, $parent = null)
{   
    $limit = explode(':',$limit);
    $parent = explode(':',$parent);
    if(count($limit) >=3)
    {
        $table = $params[0]; 
        $condition = $limit[0]." `".$limit[1]."` ".$limit[2]." ".$limit[3]." "; 
        if(count($parent)>=2 )
        {
            $row =  \DB::table($table)->where($parent[0],$parent[1])->get();
             $row =  \DB::select( "SELECT * FROM ".$table." ".$condition ." AND ".$parent[0]." = '".$parent[1]."'");
        } else  {
           $row =  \DB::select( "SELECT * FROM ".$table." ".$condition);
        }        
    }else{
        $table = $params[0]; 
        if(count($parent)>=2 )
        {
            $row =  \DB::table($table)->where($parent[0],$parent[1])->get();
        } else  {
            $row =  \DB::table($table)->get();
        }              
    }
    return $row;
}
```

This code is using http://carlosdeoliveira.net/jcombo/?lang=en. If you look up to the example on the project link you will see that it is using parent (state) to list the child (cities) for listings. I am not using the parent so nothing is assinged to variables $parent[0] and $parent[ 1 ], thus nothing to worry about but for the rest, I will try to post each result below so, you would have a better idea. My understanding is that the model.php is passing the data to controllers.php using  `$row =  \DB::table($table)->get();` If you look to the screenshot, you will see that I have more then 1 column to list the options. I cannot write a single column name there if I write `$row = \DB::table($table)->whereRaw('lunch <> ""')->get();` this brings the options until the Id 4. In this case Holland is not in the option list for guest origin.

Once the model.php passes `$row` to controllers.php, It' returning the following results for each variable.

```
print_r($row);
```

> stdClass Object ( [id] => 48 [guest_origin] => Other [heard_where] =>
>   [staying_at] => [lunch_option] => )

```
print_r($rows);
```

> Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array (
>   [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [guest_origin] => Western Australia
>   [heard_where] => Wildsights Office [staying_at] => Wildsights Villas
>   [lunch_option] => Chicken ) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7zdS.png) => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2
>   [guest_origin] => Rest of Australia [heard_where] => Brochure
>   [staying_at] => Wildsights Beach Units [lunch_option] => Cheese ) [2]
>   => stdClass Object ( [id] => 3 [guest_origin] => Germany & Austria [heard_where] => Sign [staying_at] => Bay Lodge Backpackers
>   [lunch_option] => Ham ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 4
>   [guest_origin] => UK & Eire [heard_where] => Word of Mouth
>   [staying_at] => Blue Dolphin Caravan Park [lunch_option] => Tuna )

```
print_r($fields);
```

> Array ( [0] => staying_at )

```
print_r($value);
```

prints nothing

```
print_r($items);
```

> [8] => Array ( [0] => Shark Bay Holiday Cottages [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7zdS.png) => Shark Bay
>   Holiday Cottages ) [9] => Array ( [0] => Shark Bay Hotel [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7zdS.png) => Shark
>   Bay Hotel )

Hope it is clear and you can help me to filter the empty rows before it goes into loop.

Comment: `WHERE lunch is not null`

Comment: my columns are like this $parent[0],$parent[1]

Comment: I am not sure how to write `is not null` I tried `$row =  \DB::table($table)->whereNotNull('lunch')->get();` but didn't work for me.

Comment: try `where('lunch', '!=', '""')`

Comment: I see. I wasn't using null in database that's why it didn't work.

Comment: you need to set the default null value, to avoid that in the future, you may remove the question or answer it with the solution

Comment: sorry, using null in database didn't solve the problem I still have empty options in the selectbox. Not my outputs are like this `12
:
["Other", "Other "]
13
:
[null, " "]
14
:
[null, " "]`

Comment: If I use `$row = \DB::table($table)->whereNotNull('lunch')->get();`
it takes only the first few rows for the other selectboxes.
`print_r($items)` prints me this: `[19] => Array ( [0] => DMMVC [1] => DMMVC ) [20] => Array ( [0] => [1] => ) [21] => Array ( [0] => [1] => ) [22] => Array ( [0] => [1] => ) [23] => Array ( [0] => [1] => ) [24] => Array ( [0] => [1] => ) [25] => Array ( [0] => [1] => ) [26] => Array ( [0] => [1] => ) [27] => Array ( [0] => [1] => )` so Before I get the model in the conroller can I filter the rows? `$rows = $this->model->getComboselect($param,$limit,$parent);`

Comment: @hijacker83 are you there?

Comment: lets have chat over this issue

Answer (score 22):

The most appropriate way would be to use `whereRaw` operator rather then `where`.

e.x The following query will fetch all data except empty`("")` values in the field list.

```
DB::table('mytable')->whereRaw('field <> ""')->get();
```

Comment: very useful code. I have updated my first post. Could you please have a look. I believe it is explaining more now and you should able to understand why I cannot use `DB::table('mytable')->whereRaw('field <> ""')->get();` in this case.

Comment: Elegant solution. The only simple solution that helped to check for empty values!

Comment: Just commenting in case anyone finds this useful. I was able to use this code snippet  but had to make a small tweak for it to work with postgres. The error I got was `Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"`. Switching to `->whereRaw("field <> ''")` seemed to do the trick. I guess double quotes here was not a meaningful identifier for psql

Answer (score 18):

You can use macro, it checks field for not null and not empty string. Just add these lines of code into your AppServiceProvider

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder as QueryBuilder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder as EloquentBuilder;

public function boot()
{
    QueryBuilder::macro(
        'whereNotEmpty',
        function (string $column) {
            return $this->whereNotNull($column)
                ->where($column, '<>', '');
        }
    );

    EloquentBuilder::macro(
        'whereNotEmpty',
        function (string $column) {
            return $this->getQuery()
                ->whereNotEmpty($column);
        }
    );
}
```

And now you allow to use this like that:

```php
$posts = Post::whereNotEmpty('field')->get();
```

Comment: This is the great answer

Answer (score 2):

```
->whereNotNull('<field>')
```

As an alternative, this works for me